# Using Buildozer in Docker - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2

Tags: python, docker, kivy, ubuntu-16.04, buildozer

I have built a docker image as an environment for Kivy/Python development. I can run the code no problem and I've been able to complete several Kivy tutorials.

Now, I am at the point where I'm learning to compile my Kivy apps; but when I try to use Buildozer to compile an apk, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- 
packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 
122, in __init__
self.config.read(filename)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 696, in read
self._read(fp, filename)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/configparser.py", line 1012, in _read
for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 
1661: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried to find a solution for this by searching for this section of the terminal output with no success `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 
1661: ordinal not in range(128)` - none of the results seemed to be directly related to my situation.

I'd love to list everything I've tried, but if I'm being honest, I'm very much a novice developer and I've managed to thoroughly confuse myself here.

If anyone could instruct me as to how to approach this problem and resolve it, I would much appreciate it.

This is the simple app I was trying to compile first - nothing fancy:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
    f = FloatLayout()
    s = Scatter() 
    l= Label(text="Hello World!",
             font_size=150)
    # variables children of 'f'
    f.add_widget(s)
    s.add_widget(l)
    return f

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Comment: What docker image are you using? Maybe this will solve the problem: [https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/77#issuecomment-319206865](https://github.com/pytorch/text/issues/77#issuecomment-319206865)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and building from there...but, you're comment may have just sent me down the right path. I'll report back shortly...thank you, @Jatimir

Comment: Can you post your buildozer.spec?

Comment: @Tshirtman - thanks for the offering to look into it, but I ended up finding a solution. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have arrived at an answer to this problem and I'd like to thank @Jatmir for sending my down the right path in the comments to the question.

The issue is that the base-Ubuntu-image I used does not include any locales by default. In order to add them to the image I was building, I added the following commands to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
RUN update-locale en_US.UTF-8
```

Then, I just ran these commands in the container and committed it:

```
export LC_ALL=$(locale -a | grep en_US)
export LANG=$(locale -a | grep en_US)
```

Alternatively, you could add these variables to either the Dockerfile, or declare them in run the command. Any of said approaches should work.